# Wait for download to complete in BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, asynchronous, backgroundworker, webclient

I have a Dialog with a progressbar. A Backgroundworker should download two files (with the WebClient) and copy them to a specified location automatically, when the Dialog is shown.
How can I wait for the files to be downloaded before copying the new files.

I have tried to do something with `await`, but I cant change the Backgroundworker to a async method. How can I wait in the worker for the download to complete?

Code to run the worker:

```
private void fmUpdateingDatabaseDialog_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    device.Connect();
    lbInformation.Text = "uploading database to " + device.FriendlyName;
    device.Disconnect();

    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
    worker.ProgressChanged += 
        new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += 
        new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Code in DoWork handler (paths are not empty in actual code):

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    //download files temporary
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
    client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(""), Path.Combine(tempPath + ""));

    WebClient client2 = new WebClient();
    client2.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client2_DownloadProgressChanged);
    client2.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(""), Path.Combine(tempPath + ""));

    //upload files to phone
    device.Connect();
        device.TransferContentToDevice(Path.Combine(tempPath+""), folder.Id, folder, true);
        device.TransferContentToDevice(Path.Combine(tempPath+""), folder.Id, folder, true);
    device.Disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this, which uses a ["wait and pulse"](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Signaling_with_Wait_and_Pulse) mechanism to delay the code until your download operation has completed:

```
var locker = new object(); 

Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        //peform your downloading operation, and wait for it to finish.
        client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(""), Path.Combine(tempPath + ""));
        while (/* not yet downloaded */) { }; 
        //inform the parent thread that the download has finished.
        Monitor.Pulse(locker);
    }
}));

t.Start();

lock(locker)
{
    Monitor.Wait(locker);
}
```

However, if you have the resources, I'd suggest refactoring your code to entirely use an async-await approach (thus obviating the background worker).  The background worker is one of the legacy asynchronous approaches while the recommended approach is [TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

See Stephen Cleary's answer for an example of how to do this.

Comment: -, **do never ever not suggest Thread.Sleep (of any kind, whether it be 0 or 1000) and a loop for such a sencario**, rather go for WaitHandles! (see my full why/how/... @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815895/why-is-thread-sleep-so-harmful/8815944#8815944)

Comment: I thought of that, but it seemed a little bit dirty to me.
Do you have resources for an async-await approach?
I would not know how to start an async function from the Dialog_shown event

Comment: @roryap your edit didn't make it better, rather even worse. "loop + `Thread.Sleep`" stays evil for soo many reasons. Also, your solution might not be release-build compatible as there might be a chance that the compiler will remove your comparison to a constant value ... Everytime one promotes "loop + `Thread.Sleep`" a kitten dies.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair -- my provided solution is simply a stop-gap measure, but my overall recommendation is to go to TAP.

Comment: @roryap still, a kitten is caught in purgatory, unless you replace the first part with a WaitHandle-solution, albeit your preferred solution...

Comment: Thank you for your discussion.
I used a WaitHandle to solve my problem.

Comment: isn't there a possibility that the second `lock(locker)` is executed first and that it then just waits for the `Monitor.Wait(locker);` call and never enters the Thread block? That looks like a deadlock to me. However, I might be misinterpreting how Monitor handles this.

Comment: @Default nope, `Monitor.Wait` releases the wait, so that the `lock` in the task can aquire and pulse it. Please see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28785/Thread-synchronization-Wait-and-Pulse-demystified: *If thread A holds the lock on the key object, why does thread B not block when it tries to acquire the lock? This is, of course, handled properly. The call to Wait in thread A releases the lock before it waits. This allows thread B to acquire the lock and call Pulse. ...*

Comment: @Default -- No, as Andreas just said.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.wait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) "Releases the lock on an object and blocks the current thread until it reacquires the lock."

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the synchronous `WebClient` methods (e.g., `DownloadFile` instead of `DownloadFileTaskAsync`), or you can just use `async`/`await` directly *instead* of `BackgroundWorker`. In this case, you're doing mainly I/O, so `async` is a better fit than `BackgroundWorker`.

An `async` solution would look something like this:

```
private async void fmUpdateingDatabaseDialog_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  device.Connect();
  lbInformation.Text = "uploading database to " + device.FriendlyName;
  device.Disconnect();

  var progress = new Progress<T>(data =>
  {
    // TODO: move worker_ProgressChanged code into here.
  });
  await DownloadAsync(progress);
  // TODO: move worker_RunWorkerCompleted code here.
}

private async Task DownloadAsync(IProgress<T> progress)
{
  //download files temporary
  WebClient client = new WebClient();
  client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
  await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(""), Path.Combine(tempPath + ""));

  WebClient client2 = new WebClient();
  client2.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client2_DownloadProgressChanged);
  await client2.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(""), Path.Combine(tempPath + ""));

  //upload files to phone
  // TODO: Check for Async versions of these methods that you can await.
  //  If there aren't any, consider using Task.Run.
  device.Connect();
  device.TransferContentToDevice(Path.Combine(tempPath+""), folder.Id, folder, true);
  device.TransferContentToDevice(Path.Combine(tempPath+""), folder.Id, folder, true);
  device.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but I thought I can use `await` only in async methods. Since `fmUpdateingDatabaseDialog_Shown` is not async, i dont know how to implement this.
Edit: I don't synchronos WebClient because seeing the progress is important.

Comment: May I ask what your view of `async void` is? [I read an article that it should be avoided](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/) and I've seen you around here on SO answering a lot of Task questions :) I figured your view on the matter might be very interesting.

Comment: You should avoid `async void`. `async void` should only be used for event handlers (or for things that are logically event handlers, such as `ICommand.Execute`). In this case, `fmUpdateingDatabaseDialog_Shown` is an event handler, so `async void` is acceptable. `DownloadAsync` is not an event handler, so `async void` would be wrong for that method. I have [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) that goes into more detail.