# I use a thread for the UI display in WPF program(c#), but the CPU is high. I am not sure why

Tags: c#, ui-thread

I programming a c# code, I just used a thread to display a data on the UI, once per 100 ms. But I found the CPU(not the memory) is very high, from 20% to 70% immediately. Could someone else help me for this problem?

```
    public delegate void ThreadDisplayDelegate(string message);
    public ThreadDisplayDelegate _threaddelegate;
    public void DisplayCurrentDialog(string message)
    {
        if (_UI_receive.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            _UI_receive.Text = message;
        }
        else
        {
            _UI_receive.Dispatcher.Invoke(_threaddelegate, message);
        }
    }
    public void ThreadUIDisplay()
    {
        _threaddelegate = new ThreadDisplayDelegate(DisplayCurrentDialog);
        while (_continue)
        {              
            DisplayCurrentDialog(_m_received_message);                
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is related to this piece of code? Your code is not related to serial communication. How is serial communication done?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815895/why-is-thread-sleep-so-harmful

Comment: What does the UI do when it updates?

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is the problem of this piece of code. After I commented out this piece of code, this problem do not shown again.

Comment: it is used to show a real-time data (_m_received_message).

Comment: I don't think it is caused by Thread.Sleep(100). Because I used it in another thread, but it do not have the problem there.

Comment: I believe the Invoke is the one causing the issue. Can you not use BeginInvoke to make it asynchornous?

Comment: The `Sleep` has a bad smell for me. It's not that it is this call that is eating your CPU for lunch, but it blocks the calling thread for 100 ms every time `ThreadUIDisplay()` is called, and that seems undesirable.

Comment: So if you comment out the `while (_continue)` block of code, does the issue go away?  Also, using `Task.Delay` instead of `Sleep` will not block the thread.

Comment: I use BeginInvoke instead. It is perfect, thank you all guys. I have solved this problem. Task.Delay seems not work for this problem.