# C# selenium I want to dismiss WhatsApp alert using automation but it's not working

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=%2B0000000000000&text=I%27m+interested+in+your+car+for+sale&type=phone_number&app_absent=0");
Thread.Sleep(5000);
driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Dismiss();
```

I want to dismiss WhatsApp alert, that asking me to open whatsapp application. as well as i am getting exeption that OpenQA.Selenium.NoAlertPresentException: `no such alert (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.120)`
The picture below shows my problem.

[image]

I want to dismiss that notification so that the URL will take me to the contact which i want to message

Comment: Are you getting an exception message, or is nothing happening at all?

Comment: it's giving an exception message like  ```OpenQA.Selenium.NoAlertPresentException: 'no such alert
  (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.120)```

Comment: `Alert().Dismiss()` is for JS alerts... I'm pretty sure this is a browser-specific alert and does not qualify. Selenium will not work on any browser specific UI elements. You can try sendkeys but I don't think that will work either. You will likely have to use a different Windows UI library or create a profile where that URL is already accepted and load it using Selenium at the start of the test.

Comment: @JeffC can you help me with this please ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the same problem as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1570644/launch-whatsapp-web-from-url) so following this answer instead of simulate clicking just replace `api.whatsapp.com` in the URL with `web.whatsapp.com`.

e.g. (referring to your case)

```
String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=%2B0000000000000&text=I%27m+interested+in+your+car+for+sale&type=phone_number&app_absent=0";
url = url.Replace("api.whatsapp.com", "web.whatsapp.com");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

If you need to use it as a part of some e2e test then you can read the URL from the browser using `url =  driver.Url;`, do replacement and again navigate to the new URL.

```
// doing some stuff with driver what causes navigation to WhatsApp
String url = driver.Url;
url = url.Replace("api.whatsapp.com", "web.whatsapp.com");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

`Thread.Sleep(5000);` is no needed. Additionally, I can elaborate, that `Thread.Sleep(5000);` is generally considered as a bad practice. It is explained in details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8815944/21085370).

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include specific details about how this addresses the problem in the question, including any and all code changes necessary to do this? As it stands, this answer reads more like a comment.

Comment: That is better, but typically we include enough of the OP's code to understand how to apply this. Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: @GregBurghardt
Ok. I explained reading URL from the browser, and referred to Thread.Sleep(). Anything more can be added?

Comment: Much better! Welcome to the site!