# How to retry a SOAP call using a WebService Extension (at the server, not client)

Tags: soapexception, soap-extension

I have developed a SOAP service that accesses a finicky back-end across a WAN. I want to implement retry logic to save the consumer apps from implementing retry logic.

[Cleanest way to write retry logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563191/c-sharp-cleanest-way-to-write-retry-logic) has some interesting ideas, but I would like to avoid complicating the code across dozens of calls.

I think I need to implement a SOAPExtension to check for retrySpecific exceptions and then perform an internal retry.

**P-Code:** 

SOAP Call Enters WebService 
Call to back-end is made 
If Pass, return data 
If Fail, Call to back-end is made 
If Pass, return data 
If Fail, retrun exception

Any ideas on how to implement this ?