# Implementing correct completion of a retryable block

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

**Teaser**: guys, this question is not about how to implement retry policy. It's about correct completion of a TPL Dataflow block.

This question is mostly a continuation of my previous question [Retry policy within ITargetBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17469689/102112). The answer to this question was @svick's smart solution that utilizes `TransformBlock` (source) and `TransformManyBlock` (target). The only problem left is to complete this block in a *right way*: wait for all the retries to be completed first, and then complete the target block. Here is what I ended up with (it's just a snippet, don't pay too many attention to a non-threadsafe `retries` set):

```
var retries = new HashSet<RetryingMessage<TInput>>();

TransformManyBlock<RetryableMessage<TInput>, TOutput> target = null;
target = new TransformManyBlock<RetryableMessage<TInput>, TOutput>(
    async message =>
    {
        try
        {
            var result = new[] { await transform(message.Data) };
            retries.Remove(message);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message.Exceptions.Add(ex);
            if (message.RetriesRemaining == 0)
            {
                if (failureHandler != null)
                    failureHandler(message.Exceptions);

                retries.Remove(message);
            }
            else
            {
                retries.Add(message);
                message.RetriesRemaining--;

                Task.Delay(retryDelay)
                    .ContinueWith(_ => target.Post(message));
            }
            return null;
        }
    }, dataflowBlockOptions);

source.LinkTo(target);

source.Completion.ContinueWith(async _ =>
{
    while (target.InputCount > 0 || retries.Any())
        await Task.Delay(100);

    target.Complete();
});
```

The idea is to perform some kind of polling and verify whether there are still messages that waiting to be processed and there are no messages that require retrying. But in this solution I don't like the idea of polling.

Yes, I can encapsulate the logic of adding/removing retries into a separate class, and even e.g. perform some action when the set of retries becomes empty, but how to deal with `target.InputCount > 0` condition? There is not such a callback that get called when there are no pending messages for the block, so it seems that verifying `target.ItemCount` in a loop with a small delay is an only option.

Does anybody knows a smarter way to achieve this?

Comment: It would appear that ITargetBlock supports push-based notification via an observer returned by the AsObserver Extension method. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160359.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee850490.aspx.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use exceptions as normal program flow, which is bad practice. 

Search Google or look at the following topic on SO:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control

All the retry logic should be in the try block, not in the exception block. Not an answer to your question but something I thought you should know.

Comment: @Nullius, retry logic is based on *exceptions* - retry in case of transient error. I don't think that retry logic in a `try` block is a good idea, since you don't know the error type and whether this kind of error is transient or not.

Comment: Are you open to using the Enterprise Lib retry policies? No need to reinvent the wheel, you can just extend one.

Comment: @georgiosd: *Transient Fault Handling Application Block* from EntLib (or *Transient Fault Handling Core* nuget package) doesn't cover my needs - this is explained in this and my previous questions.

Comment: You can rely more on TPL. Single responsibility principle also works for blocks! you're transform block in this case should only be responsible for executing your message. After which send it to another block which, in turn, will decide whether to dump the message, forward it to the transform block again for retryal or forward it to the next block.

Comment: @ Alex RE: @Nullius I think he is referring to the fact you should only raise the exception after the retries have failed, so if you know that condition x will result in an exception you test for it before you perform the action, then you would enter your wait retry loop then, only when that still fails, raise the exception. raising an exception is expensive so should only be done when the problem is totally unpredictable or or when you need to pass complex information about the error to the calling routine for it to be handled correctly

Comment: Ummm.... just a though, what about adding retries to another `TransformManyBlock`, and ContinueWith that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining hwcverwe answer and  JamieSee comment could be the ideal solution.

First, you need to create more than one event:

```
var signal  = new ManualResetEvent(false);
var completedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

Then, you have to create an observer, and subscribe to the `TransformManyBlock`, so you are notified when a relevant event happens:

```
var observer = new RetryingBlockObserver<TOutput>(completedEvent);
var observable = target.AsObservable();
observable.Subscribe(observer);
```

The observable can be quite easy:

```
private class RetryingBlockObserver<T> : IObserver<T> {
        private ManualResetEvent completedEvent;

        public RetryingBlockObserver(ManualResetEvent completedEvent) {                
            this.completedEvent = completedEvent;
        }

        public void OnCompleted() {
            completedEvent.Set();
        }

        public void OnError(Exception error) {
            //TODO
        }

        public void OnNext(T value) {
            //TODO
        }
    }
```

And you can wait for either the signal, or completion (exhaustion of all the source items), or both

```
 source.Completion.ContinueWith(async _ => {

            WaitHandle.WaitAll(completedEvent, signal);
            // Or WaitHandle.WaitAny, depending on your needs!

            target.Complete();
        });
```

You can inspect the result value of WaitAll to understand which event was set, and react accordingly. 
You can also add other events to the code, passing them to the observer, so that it can set them when needed. You can differentiate your behaviour and respond differently when an error is raised, for example

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) can do the trick for you.

Add a public property to `TransformManyBlock`

```
private ManualResetEvent _signal  = new ManualResetEvent(false);
public ManualResetEvent Signal { get { return _signal; } }
```

And here you go:

```
var retries = new HashSet<RetryingMessage<TInput>>();

TransformManyBlock<RetryableMessage<TInput>, TOutput> target = null;
target = new TransformManyBlock<RetryableMessage<TInput>, TOutput>(
    async message =>
    {
        try
        {
            var result = new[] { await transform(message.Data) };
            retries.Remove(message);

            // Sets the state of the event to signaled, allowing one or more waiting threads to proceed
            if(!retries.Any()) Signal.Set(); 
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message.Exceptions.Add(ex);
            if (message.RetriesRemaining == 0)
            {
                if (failureHandler != null)
                    failureHandler(message.Exceptions);

                retries.Remove(message);

                // Sets the state of the event to signaled, allowing one or more waiting threads to proceed
                if(!retries.Any()) Signal.Set(); 
            }
            else
            {
                retries.Add(message);
                message.RetriesRemaining--;

                Task.Delay(retryDelay)
                    .ContinueWith(_ => target.Post(message));
            }
            return null;
        }
    }, dataflowBlockOptions);

source.LinkTo(target);

source.Completion.ContinueWith(async _ =>
{
    //Blocks the current thread until the current WaitHandle receives a signal.
    target.Signal.WaitOne();

    target.Complete();
});
```

I am not sure where your `target.InputCount` is set. So at the place you change `target.InputCount` you can add following code:

```
if(InputCount == 0)  Signal.Set();
```

Comment: The thing is: `target.InputCount` is a *black box* - it's a read-only property of `TransformManyBlock` from TPL Dataflow.