# Why is cancelling Task.Delay slow?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I've created a test program that runs 1000 Tasks which perform `Task.Delay` with a random delay between 20s and 30s. 
It looks like cancelling this operation takes about 10s..

Here is my test program :

```
class Program
{
    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        List<Task> allTask = new List<Task>();
        Random r = new Random(9);

        async Task SafeDelay(int delay, CancellationToken token)
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(delay, token);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            var randomDelay = r.Next(20000, 30000);
            allTask.Add(SafeDelay(randomDelay, tokenSource.Token));
            ;
        }

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        var cancelTask = Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("1000ms elapsed. Cancelation request start");;
            stopwatch.Start();
            tokenSource.Cancel();
        });

        await Task.WhenAll(allTask);
        await cancelTask;

        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"Cancelation done after {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started");
        Task.Run(MainAsync).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine("End");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

My Result with .NET Core 2.1:

```
Cancelation done after 9808ms
```

Why is cancelling Task.Delay so slow and is there a way to improve it?

My Result with .NET 4.7.1:

```
Cancelation done after 6200ms
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto No cancelation is requested before await Task.WhenAll(allTask)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I replace it with Task.Run(MainAsync).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); but I got the same result

Comment: @PabloHoney remove all calls to `ConfigureAwai()` for starters. Console applicaitons have no sync context. Remove `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` too. It doesn't do anything more than `.Wait()` in this case. Probably remove `Task.Run()` too as `MainAsync` is supposed to be asynchronous already

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I removed all ConfigureAwait(false) but I still got 10185ms

Comment: @PabloHoney there's a lot of unusual code in this snippet. Awaiters, continuations, `ConfigureAwait`. And the way `SafeDelay` is written, you're actually counting the time taken to throw 1000 exceptions

Comment: You cannot really cancel `Task` once it is started but only prevent it actually to run, while it is scheduled. In order to cancel the `Task` you need to implement that explicitly by checking `CancellationToken`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971316/when-i-use-cancelafter-the-task-is-still-running/48971668#48971668

Comment: @Johnny - `Task.Delay()` takes care of that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I took a look at the source code and realize that. Tnx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I run this with <kbd>F5</kbd> I get a similar result.
Run it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (no debugger) and it cancels in less than 50 ms.

So you are actually timing 1000 execptions tickling the debugger. The debugger might intefere with other execution points too. Always run benchmarks in Release Mode, w/o a debugger.

Comment: That's make the difference actually. ty

Answer (score 1):

No repro with the question's code. Using it as is, I get :

```
Started
1000ms elapsed. Cancelation request start
Cancelation done after 38 ms
End
```

No repro with cleaned up code :

```
static async Task SafeDelay(int delay, CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(delay, token);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
    }
}


private static async Task Main()
{
    //Set 1000 ms timeout
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(1000);
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var allTask = new List<Task>();
    Random r = new Random(9); 


    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        var randomDelay = r.Next(20000, 30000);
        allTask.Add(SafeDelay(randomDelay, tokenSource.Token));
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"All {allTask.Count} tasks running after {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

    await Task.WhenAll(allTask);
    stopwatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"Cancelation done after {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
}
```

This produces :

```
All 1000 tasks running after 8 ms
Cancelation done after 1044 ms
```

The CancellationTokenSource has a 1000ms timeout.

Comment: I run it in like 10ms too. But I  can't find any fundamental differences between your code and mine.

Comment: @PabloHoney *how* do you run it though? As for cleaning up, when faced with a complex problem or unexpected behaviour you *have* to remove anything unwanted. Otherwise you can't be certain whether you are measuring your test harness or the code

Comment: I run all the codes from VStudio hitting the play button (F5)

Comment: @PabloHoney the debugger catches and analyzes all exceptions, and enables a *lot* of diagnostic hooks in the code. You can't benchmark any code while debugging.

Comment: Yes but why does it does not do the same with your code above. I test it with F5 and I still got fast result like 10ms

Comment: @PabloHoney - that is not a question about the code but about the debugger. That might put threads on hold etc. A much more complicated question. Your ouriginal code was fine.