# Retry on exception code is not actually retrying

Tags: c#, http, httprequest, httpresponse

I have the following code...  On the first iteration, it queries the server just fine.  But if get an error, `return action()` gets called but nothing happens on Fiddler and immediately jumps to the `catch` block.  What is happening?

```
for (int retry = 0; retry < retryCount; retry++)
{
    try
    {
        return action();
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        // truncated for clarity
    }
}
```

It's called `Retry.Do(() => HttpReturnJson(request), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), 3);`

This is what my `HttpReturnJson` looks like:

**EDITED** I tried enclosing `WebResponse` and `StreamReader` inside `using` blocks... It doesn't seem to be that the **old** `WebResponse response` is getting disposed.  On the retry, I'm still reading from the old one.  How do I resend the `request` on the retry?

```
public string HttpReturnJson(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return data;
    }
}
```

**Source of this code:** [Cleanest way to write retry logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563191/c-sharp-cleanest-way-to-write-retry-logic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read same response more than once, so you need to re-send request on every retry and than read from the response.

Below is how your `HttpReturnJson` could look like for re-creating request (assuming just regular GET on known url):

```
public string HttpReturnJson(string url)
{
    using (var request = WebRequest.Create(url))
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return data;
    }
}
```

Note that if you need headers/post data you'll need to set those up too on every request.

Comment: How so I send a new request? The HttpWebRequest object remains unchanged.

Comment: @KKKKKKKK - I've added sample of `HttpReturnJson` change... As "re-send request" I meant create new `WebRequest` - should have been more clear.