# How to call any method n Times

Tags: c#

I want to create a util that will have a method "Call" which will get 3 arguments:

1. N (int) - number of times to keep invoke the method "M" if failed .
2. M ( Any type of method) he needs to invoke.
3. list of arguments x will need to be invoked with.

this method "Call" should be generic that can return any type T.

so if a method Add is:

```
public int Add(int x,int y)
```

I can write

```
int sum = util.Call<int>(2,Add,5,4);
```

so method 'Add' of 5,4 will be invoked 2 times if first call throw an exception.

Comment: 1. If the method should support "Any" signature, it'll need to use `dynamic` or `Reflection` is some way. 2. If the method throws `exception` is there a valid point in calling the same method again with same parameters?

Comment: 1 . could you reply with an example for dynamic or reflection ? 
2. the point is I will cal methods invoking rest services and some times it will trigger timeout and a second call with a delay will work. (in a time the server is down and I want to continue calling it)

Comment: Do the arguments need to change for each invoke or will they remain the same?

Comment: _"Please write the code for me"_ is usually not a good Stack Overflow question. Share your research and your progress, even if that doesn't work. Anyway see [C# cleanest way to write retry logic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563191/c-sharp-cleanest-way-to-write-retry-logic).

Comment: This can be easily done using Lambdas and Func<T>

Comment: Your `Call` method takes four arguments, not three...