# Generic Retry Logic for code where Constructor Can Throw

Tags: c#, retry-logic

Follow up from question here:
[Cleanest way to write retry logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563191/cleanest-way-to-write-retry-logic)

In the answer, a generic class to retry functions is defined and used as such:

```
Retry.Do(() => SomeFunctionThatCanFail(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

How would you implement a generic retry, where the constructor can throw also?

So I don't just want to retry:

```
   SomeFunctionThatCanFail()
```

I want to retry the following block in a generic fashion:

```
   SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
   sc.SomeFunctionThatCanFail();
```

Comment: If you don't need to access `sc` later, you could do new `Retry.Do(() => new SomeClass().SomeFunctionThatCanFail(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));`

Comment: "where Constructor Can Throw" sounds fishy to me. Yes constructor may throw but has to be something seriously wrong. Not something that might work on a 2nd try

Comment: What's wrong with putting the entire block into the lambda expression?

Comment: The supposition of the question is that the ctor can throw; presumably there is no way to *prevent* the ctor from throwing because if there was, you'd do it and then you wouldn't need to retry. But the additional supposition of the question is that *doing the same thing again will not throw*.  So, you have a ctor that throws unpredictably.  Don't put a bandaid on that code; delete it and write a ctor that behaves predictably.

Comment: @EricLippert I was actually going to link [Vexing exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/), in my post lol....

Comment: Exponential backoff is a good retry strategy than simply trying x number of times. You can use a library like Polly to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not realise I could put a block of code into the Lambda expression.  This is exactly what I want:

```
Retry.Do(() => { using (DataBaseProxy db = new DataBaseProxy(dbList.Next())) { .DoSomething(); } }, new TimeSpan(0));
```

Answer (score 3):

> where the constructor can throw also?

Generally this is a bad idea.  I would recommend looking at the Factory Pattern:

```
public class SomeClass
{
  private SomeClass()
  {
  }

  public static SomeClass GetInstance()
  {
    // Throw Exception here, not in constructor
  }

  public void SomeFunctionThatCanFail()
  {
  }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
Retry.Do(() => 
  SomeClass.GetInstance().SomeFunctionThatCanFail(), 
  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```