# How to write a timeout for short and repeatedly action?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, timeout, rabbitmq

I would like to write a timeout function for the BasicPublish method of the RabbitMQ C# client. For many reasons sometimes the queue is blocked, or rabbit is down or whatever. But I want to detect when the publish is failing right away. I do not want to block the site for any reason.

I'm worried to implement a timeout with Task or threads adding overhead for a simple publish, that we are doing it millions of times in production.

Does anyone have and idea how to write a quick timeout on a fast blocking method as BasicPublish?

Clarification: Also I'm working in .Net 4, I do not have async.

Comment: You can use `async`/`await` with .NET4.0 using the [Microsoft.BCL.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polly has a [TimeoutPolicy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout) aimed at exactly this scenario.

Polly's [`TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#optimistic-timeout) is close to @ThiagoCustodio's answer, but it also disposes the `CancellationTokenSource` correctly.  RabbitMQ's C# client doesn't however (at time of writing) offer a `BasicPublish()` overload taking `CancellationToken`, so this approach is not relevant.

Polly's [`TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#pessimistic-timeout) is aimed at scenarios such as `BasicPublish()`, where you want to impose a timeout on a delegate which *doesn't* have `CancellationToken` support.

Polly's `TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic`:

[1] allows the calling thread to time-out on (walk away from waiting for) the execution, even when the executed delegate doesn't support cancellation.

[2] does so at the cost of an extra task/thread (in synchronous executions), and manages this for you.

[3] also [captures the timed-out `Task`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#what-happens-to-the-timed-out-delegate) (the task you have walked away from).  This can be valuable for logging, and is *essential* to avoid [UnobservedTaskExceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/) - particularly in .NET4.0, where an [UnobservedTaskException can bring down your entire process](https://tpodolak.com/blog/2015/08/10/tpl-exception-handling-and-unobservedtaskexception-issue/).

Simple example:

```
Policy.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic).Execute(() => BasicPublish(...));
```

Full example properly avoiding `UnobservedTaskException`s:

```
Policy timeoutPolicy = Policy.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic, (context, timespan, task) => 
{
    task.ContinueWith(t => { // ContinueWith important!: the abandoned task may very well still be executing, when the caller times out on waiting for it! 
        if (t.IsFaulted) 
        {
            logger.Error($"{context.PolicyKey} at {context.ExecutionKey}: execution timed out after {timespan.TotalSeconds} seconds, eventually terminated with: {t.Exception}.");
        }
        else
        {
           // extra logic (if desired) for tasks which complete, despite the caller having 'walked away' earlier due to timeout.
        }
    });
});

timeoutPolicy.Execute(() => BasicPublish(...));
```

---

To avoid building up too many concurrent pending tasks/threads in the case where RabbitMQ becomes unavailable, you can use a [Bulkhead Isolation policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Bulkhead) to limit parallelization and/or a [CircuitBreaker](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Circuit-Breaker) to prevent putting calls through for a period, once you detect a certain level of failures.  These can be combined with the TimeoutPolicy using [`PolicyWrap`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the easiest way is using tasks / cancellation token. Do you think it's an overhead?

```
public static async Task WithTimeoutAfterStart(
    Func<CancellationToken, Task> operation, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var task = operation(source.Token);
    source.CancelAfter(timeout);
    await task;
}
```

Usage:

```
await WithTimeoutAfterStart(
    ct => SomeOperationAsync(ct), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(n));
```

Comment: Also you could wrap your code using Polly: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#retry and https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#retry

Comment: I do not have big knowledge about if Task really creates a thread or not and when exactly it creates a new thread. But yes I think that creating a Thread for each publish es a overhead for a publish action when everything is working ok. Also intersted library Polly, I will investigate it

Comment: Cool. In the end it's just a retry pattern encapsulated. If none of them fits your need, you can always write your own: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589788.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563191/cleanest-way-to-write-retry-logic

Comment: Circuit breaker is goog idea in general and Polly is afaik lightweight yet comfortable implementation