# Safe practice with retries

Tags: c#

I am attempting to add retries to a function but I'm unsure if the following is a safe way to do this

```
void start() 
{
    int count = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        if (!configure())
        {
            count++;
            if (count == 2)
            { 
                 //error handling

                return;  
            }
         }
         count = 0;
         break;
    }

//do other stuff

}
```

Will this work?

Comment: This will help you, take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563191/cleanest-way-to-write-retry-logic

Comment: This code will try to configure and if it fails set count to 1, set count to 0, break and end. So...no?

Comment: @Milster if I add an `else` statement before resetting count to zero and breaking will that work?

Comment: @user7827715 Please have a look at the 2 posted links. They will help you. But to answer your question, Yes, that could work. In future just try the code and step through it with your debugger. A huge part of programming is learning how to understand and analyze code.