# Retry policy for Google Drive Rest API

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I want to setup retry policy for Drive Rest API client but I can't find a way how to do it. I found only [this article](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#exponential-backoff) but it says nothing about implementations. Does it mean I should implement retry logic myself or I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to code your own retry policy. Here are some tips:-

- 401 - this is an expired access token, so get a fresh token and retry
- 403 - check the message to see if this is a "rate limit exceeded". If so, you need to  retry with a throttle. A delay of 1.5-2 seconds will normally be acceptable.
- 5xx - these are sometimes transient errors in Gdrive and sometimes a bug. Do an exponential backoff and retry, but don't bother retrying more than 3 or 4 times, because if it hasn't worked yet, it's unlikely to.

Comment: You could try to use the .NET library Polly to implement retry logic. More information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563191/cleanest-way-to-write-retry-logic?#16382831