# File.ReadAllText with a lambda-based retry wrapper on Try Catch

Tags: c#, try-catch

Trying to find the most elegant solution for a situation when  I get a "IOException: Sharing violation" on loading a JSON file because it is being saved at the same time by another application.

Using a "try Catch' with some form of recursion when loading, though inelegant, makes sense.
So after searching came across this C# solution which gets a lot of up votes
[Cleanest way to write retry logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563191/cleanest-way-to-write-retry-logic)

The actual function call where my load occurs is

```
 private static T LoadData<T>(string filePath)
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
    }
```

However not sure how to implement using the above linked solution (Retry.Do) which doesn't seem to allow passed arguments in the function call ie

```
Retry.Do(SomeFunctionThatCanFail, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a closure.

The simplest way is to use a lambda expression:

```
YourType data = Retry.Do(() => LoadData<YourType>("somefilepath"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```